# How do I sort feeds returned from Google Reader?

Tags: google-reader

When I query Google Reader for the list of subscriptions for a user, it seems to be returned in a fixed order, no matter what the order is as shown at google.com/reader.

(see http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/subscription/list for the list I'm talking about)

Each subscription returns a 'sortid', which Google Reader uses when the user rearranges subscriptions, by sending back a concatenation of all sortids in the new order after rearranging is finished.  However, that sortid never changes.

So my question is this:  How do I actually get the order the subscriptions are supposed to be in?  I've been using http://code.google.com/p/pyrfeed/wiki/GoogleReaderAPI as a reference, but it is lacking in this department, and I haven't found anything anywhere else either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the answer:

http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/preference/stream/list